# Sort a stack using k stacks, and not able to push back onto original stack

Tags: algorithm, sorting, stack

Input `k` = the number of stacks

```
input = 5, 3, 4, 1, 2
output should be  = 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

however you can only pop the input, you **cannot push to it**. `output` is also another stack which you can return and push to but cannot pop

so if `k = 1`

```
in = 5, 3, 4, 1, 2  k = (),     out = ()
in = 3, 4, 1, 2     k = 5       out = ()
in = 4, 1, 2        k = 5,3     out = ()
in = 1, 2           k = 5,3,4   out = ()
in = 2              k = 5,3,4   out = 1 // since you know 1 must go first
in = ()             k = 5,3,4   out = 1,2
```

Since you can't push back to `in`, there is no solution and you must report it.

However, there definitely are certain orderings which have solutions and may have them at different values of `k`. For example, is the above input ordering solveable if `k = 2` and have two stacks?

How would I know which stack to push to?

My thought process is

```
1. pop input
2. pop all k stacks
3. see if any popped values == target, starting with 1 and incrementing
4. if they do == target, push to out
5. if in != target, push to stack k***
```

but which stack should we push to? is where I've been stuck. If you could push back to in, this problem would be extremely easy.

This sounds like a tower of hanoi type question but I'm not sure. I feel like there's a mathematical way of solving this. Any ideas?

EDIT: Another intuition I have is that the tower of hanoi has a restriction where you cannot place a bigger peg on top of a smaller one. this makes sense also for this because say k = 1, this question is basically a tower of hanoi problem except the disks do not obey the rule initially but *should* obey the rules if a solution is possible...

Comment: The problem is always solvable for k >= 2, only if k = 1 there might be no solution. Do you need to solve it with the minimal number of steps?

Comment: For right now no but for my interests sake I would like to figure that out too

Comment: For k = 1, there's no solution (assuming data isn't already sorted). For k = 2, solutions have time complexity O(n^2). For k >= 3, variations of bottom up merge sort can be used, with time complexity O(n log(n)). For the specific case k = 3, [polyphase merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphase_merge_sort) is fastest, but it's complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two auxiliary stacks, s1, s2:

1. pop every element from original one into s1
2. pop every element from original s1 and push it into s2

   - for each passing element, retain the lesser one, don't push it until you find another lesser one
   - at the end you've got the lesser one so push it onto r
3. now repeat step 2, replacing s1 by s2 and the converse until no element

So it should looks like:

```
fill(s1,o) // step 1
u = s1, v = s2
repeat
    e = less(v,u) // step 2
    push(r,e)
    swap(u,v)
until empty(u)
```

Doesn't seem to be able to remove one auxiliary stack. I think the problem is solvable only for k>=2.

Comment: what are r and e in this case? and how does this work when the output needs to be ordered? I’m not entirely sure I understand your explanation

Comment: This is pseudo code, e an element of the stack, r result stack, u and v references to stacks. o original stack, s1 and s2 auxiliary stacks

Comment: Ok I get it. And I worked it out such push(r,e) evaluates to either s2 or out depending on whether the target number is reached. It seems like a long wind extrapolation of that sort where you just keep looking for the specific value

Comment: one of the constraints on this problem in the way I’m solving it is that swap(u,v) is illegal. I think that changes the answer a lot but the basic idea is still the samd

Comment: swap only means swap the two references, not swaping the content.